# Execute Reader is not returning a result

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-core-mvc

Can you please help me see what is wrong with my code? If I run the stored procedure using the a parameter for `Id`, I get a result in SQL Server. But when I use the code below using the same value for `Id`, in my `if(rdr.HasRows)..` I get a false.

```
public Student Find(int key)
{
    string connectionPath = ConnectionStrings.DbConnection;
    Student student = null;

    try
    {
        using(var sqlCon = new SqlConnection(connectionPath))
        {
            sqlCon.Open();

            using(var cmd = new SqlCommand("Sp_FindStudent", sqlCon))
            {
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Id", key);

                using(var rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.SingleResult))
                {
                    if (rdr.HasRows)
                    {
                        while (rdr.Read())
                        {
                            student = new Student
                            {
                                Age = Convert.ToInt32(rdr["Age"]),
                                FirstName = rdr["FirstName"].ToString(),
                                LastName = rdr["LastName"].ToString(),
                                Gender = rdr["Gender"].ToString()
                            };
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        throw ex;
    }

    return student;
}
```

If I try to get all records, I don't get any problems:

```
public IEnumerable<Student> GetAll()
{
    var studentList = new List<Student>();

    try
    {
        string connectionPath = ConnectionStrings.DbConnection;

        using(var sqlCon = new SqlConnection(connectionPath))
        {
            using(var cmd = new SqlCommand("Sp_GetStudents", sqlCon) { CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure})
            {
                sqlCon.Open();

                using(var rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection))
                {
                    while (rdr.Read())
                    {
                        studentList.Add
                            (
                                new Student
                                {
                                    Id = Convert.ToInt32(rdr["Id"]),
                                    Age = Convert.ToInt32(rdr["Age"]),
                                    FirstName = rdr["FirstName"].ToString(),
                                    LastName = rdr["LastName"].ToString()
                                }
                            );
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    } 
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        throw ex;
    }

    return studentList;
}
```

This is using asp.net core

Comment: Side note: you should **not** use the `sp_` prefix for your stored procedures. Microsoft has [reserved that prefix for its own use (see *Naming Stored Procedures*)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190669%28v=sql.105%29.aspx), and you do run the risk of a name clash sometime in the future. [It's also bad for your stored procedure performance](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix). It's best to just simply avoid `sp_` and use something else as a prefix - or no prefix at all!

Comment: Thank you for sharing this with us. It’ll make my naming convention better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code for `Find` lacks the definition that this is a **stored procedure** that you're calling.

If you look at your `GetAll`, you have:

```
using(var cmd = new SqlCommand("Sp_GetStudents", sqlCon) { CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure})
```

defining this `SqlCommand` to be a stored procedure - this setting is **missing** from your `Find` code:

```
using(var cmd = new SqlCommand("Sp_FindStudent", sqlCon))
```

I'm pretty sure it'll work if you add that:

```
using(var cmd = new SqlCommand("Sp_FindStudent", sqlCon) { CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure}))
```

Comment: Yes it did. I missed that. Thank you.